# What should I put as package name in "Generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID" step?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am following the "Get Started with Play Games Services for Android" at [Get Started with Play Games Services for Android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#before_you_begin).

In step 3 "Generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID" I have to fill the "Package name" field.

My question is very simple: What should I type there as the package name? An arbitrary one like com.google.blahblah or does it have to be my Android app package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be your Android package name, the one you specify in your Android manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.android.basiccontactables"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Here, whatever is in the package attribute should be specified in the Generate client ID step.

Comment: Alright thanks. Couldn't they just leave a simple hint next to each field to guide the beginners? I wonder.

Comment: In Android development, whenever they refer package generically, it refers to your app package name, which you give while creating the app project, which sits in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: When generating a project in android studio, the application ID matches the package name. The package in the manifest corresponds to the package (namespace) of the code. The application ID is used by to identify the app and must be different for each app and can be changed to differ from the package name. Most Google APIs require that app ID, yet still call it package name.
In my opinion this answer is wrong, the value of the package attribute is irrelevant.
Googles docs also refer to this attribute, but they also state that it's best practice to keep them the same